# .on JQuery without Click Event for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding a `table` and `rows` on a div dynamically via `Ajax`. The table and the new rows appear after a `toggle` event on a `GridView`. I want to add a table sorter on the newly created table. At the moment I'm able to do that only via the `click event`.

Is there a way to apply the sorting without the click event?

```
     $("#tbl_" + batchId).on({
         click: function(event) {
           $(this).tablesorter();
          }
     });
```

Comment: No, **event** delegation only works for... **events**. use the ajax callback.

Comment: @KevinB Great idea. You can answer the question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

After you have added. You run this command:

```
$("#tbl_" + batchId).tablesorter();
```